# Is A Purely Reflexive Relation Automatically Transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

For a given set $A$, such that $A = \{a, b, c, d\}$, and a relation on $A$, $R=\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)\}$

Since transitivity is defined as: 
$$\forall x,y,z \in A : (x R y \land y R z)\to x R z$$

And if $x, y, z = a$ for instance, then we have all $(x,y), (y,z),(x,z)$ and so on for all other elements in $A$.

Does this mean that the relation satisfies all requirements for transitivity?

Comment: Yes, it does. Any “purely reflexive” relation (meaning reflexive and all related pairs are doubles, I presume) is in fact a subrelaton of the *equality* relation.

Comment: Yes.  Note that your relation is also symmetric.  It is indeed a very simple equivalence relation.

Comment: Indeed, it is an equivalence relation but a very boring one: all equivalence classes are singletons.

Comment: @max_zorn  Equality is not boring.

Comment: Moreover, it is the only equivalence relation on a given set, that is also a partial order relation. Now, how can that be boring @max_zorn? :)

Comment: The point of studying equivalence classes is to see interesting patterns. This won't happen here though because the quotient set can be identified with the original set.

Comment: If you've made it this far through the comments in this thread, you must be truly bored.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Such a relation is indeed a transitive relation, since the only relevant cases for the premise "$xRy \land yRz$" are $x=y=z$ in such relations. Since the premise never holds for cases where $x,y,z$ are not all the same, there is no need to consider them.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*